# Pattern matching with regular expression in spark dataframes using spark-shell

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

Suppose we are given dataset ("DATA") like :

```
YEAR | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | VARIABLES
2008 | JOY        | ANDERSON  | spark|python|scala; 45;w/o sports;w datascience
2008 | STEVEN     | JOHNSON   | Spark|R; 90|56
2006 | NIHA       | DIVA      | w/o sports
```

and we have another dataset ("RESULT") like :

```
YEAR | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME 
1992 | EMMA       | CENA 
2008 | JOY        | ANDERSON
2008 | STEVEN     | ANDERSON
2006 | NIHA       | DIVA
and so on.
```

The output should be ("RESULT") :

```
YEAR | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | SUBJECT | SCORE | SPORTS | DATASCIENCE
1992 | EMMA       | CENA      |         |       |        |              
2008 | JOY        | ANDERSON  | SPARK   | 45    | FALSE  | TRUE
2008 | JOY        | ANDERSON  | PYTHON  | 45    | FALSE  | TRUE
2008 | JOY        | ANDERSON  | SCALA   | 45    | FALSE  | TRUE
2008 | STEVEN     | ANDERSON  |         |       |        | 
2006 | NIHA       | DIVA      |         |       | FALSE  | 
2008 | STEVEN     | JOHNSON   | SPARK   | 90    |        |
2008 | STEVEN     | JOHNSON   | SPARK   | 56    |        |
2008 | STEVEN     | JOHNSON   | R       | 90    |        |
2008 | STEVEN     | JOHNSON   | R       | 56    |        |
and so on.
```

Please note that there are some rows in DATA which are not present in RESULT and vice-versa. For eg - "2008,STEVEN,JOHNSON" is not present in RESULT but is present in DATA. And the entries should be made in RESULT dataset. The columns {SUBJECT, SCORE, SPORTS, DATASCIENCE} are made by my intuition that "spark" refers to the SUBJECT and so on. 
Hope you understand my query. And I am using spark-shell with spark dataframes. 
Note that "Spark" and "spark" should be considered as same.

Comment: Seems very similar to your previous question, which was answered perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146760/splitting-row-in-multiple-row-in-spark-shell - you should be able to extrapolate that answer to this. Otherwise, please give a minimal example and show the code you've tried so far.

Comment: yes it was similar but not exactly what I want to ask coz I have two different datasets and I want mapping from DATA --> RESULT. 
Previous question was different. I tried that but didn't get expected result coz I've not asked it correctly.

Comment: For the w and w/o stuff, you might also be interested in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020082/how-to-output-multiple-key-value-in-spark-map-function. Do you have a single column w/o and w? Or do you have an arbitrary number of them each time followed by the excluded/included keyword?

Comment: @Wilmerton I've total 28 type of values in VARIABLES but I narrowed it down to 4 just for the sake of understanding but in some values I do not have w or w/o symbol like in subject I have "Spark, python, scala etc". And I will check your mentioned link.

Comment: for "merging" the two datasets, just search for question about `join` and dataframes, there are plenty of examples

Comment: @ishan Ha. But specifically, do you have things like `w sports datascience` or would it be `w sports; w datascience`. Your problem is quite complex, so try to provide an exemple that covers it well. Brute force regexp are really specific, and in complex cases, they might not be the right solution at all, even when they work (maintainability + generalisation problems). You might then prefer better organised Scala code. Performance is not all when working with messy data.

Comment: @Wilmerton "w" means "with" and "w/o" means "without". So, if it is "w" then its value is TRUE else FALSE.

Comment: @ishan I understood that, it is not my question. If you have several TRUE, are they in the same "w" field, or in separate "w" fields?

Comment: also, you have two datasets that you refer to as "RESULT"...

Comment: @TzachZohar I've tried it but it is not working well. Even spliiting of rows is not giving expected result. So, I thought that it will be better if I ask it thoroughly and to the exact point. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Wilmerton RESULT is a single dataset, the second one. I want the values to be stored from DATA to RESULT.

Comment: ok. as @TzachZohar says, it's just a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you have can implement some of the tricky logic as in answers to [splitting row in multiple row in spark-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146760/splitting-row-in-multiple-row-in-spark-shell)

data:

```
val df = List(
("2008","JOY       ","ANDERSON ","spark|python|scala;45;w/o sports;w datascience"),
("2008","STEVEN    ","JOHNSON  ","Spark|R;90|56"),
("2006","NIHA      ","DIVA     ","w/o sports")
).toDF("YEAR","FIRST NAME","LAST NAME","VARIABLE")
```

I only highlight the relatively tricky parts, you can figure it out the details yourself. I suggest to handle "w" and "w/o" tags separately. Furthermore, you have to explode the language in separate "sql" statements. This give

```
val step1 = df.withColumn("backrefReplace",split(regexp_replace('VARIABLE,"^([A-z|]+)?;?([\\d\\|]+)?;?(w.*)?$","$1"+sep+"$2"+sep+"$3"),sep))
  .withColumn("letter",explode(split('backrefReplace(0),"\\|")))
  .select('YEAR,$"FIRST NAME",$"LAST NAME",'VARIABLE,'letter,
    explode(split('backrefReplace(1),"\\|")).as("digits"),
    'backrefReplace(2).as("tags")
  )
```

which gives

```
scala> step1.show(false)
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+------+------------------------+
|YEAR|FIRST NAME|LAST NAME|VARIABLE                                      |letter|digits|tags                    |
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+------+------------------------+
|2008|JOY       |ANDERSON |spark|python|scala;45;w/o sports;w datascience|spark |45    |w/o sports;w datascience|
|2008|JOY       |ANDERSON |spark|python|scala;45;w/o sports;w datascience|python|45    |w/o sports;w datascience|
|2008|JOY       |ANDERSON |spark|python|scala;45;w/o sports;w datascience|scala |45    |w/o sports;w datascience|
|2008|STEVEN    |JOHNSON  |Spark|R;90|56                                 |Spark |90    |                        |
|2008|STEVEN    |JOHNSON  |Spark|R;90|56                                 |Spark |56    |                        |
|2008|STEVEN    |JOHNSON  |Spark|R;90|56                                 |R     |90    |                        |
|2008|STEVEN    |JOHNSON  |Spark|R;90|56                                 |R     |56    |                        |
|2006|NIHA      |DIVA     |w/o sports                                    |      |      |w/o sports              |
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+------+------------------------+
```

Then you have to handle capitalisation, and the tags. For the tags, you can have a relatively generic code using `explode` and `pivot`, but you have to do some cleaning to match your exact result. Here is an example:

```
List(("a;b;c")).toDF("str")
  .withColumn("char",explode(split('str,";")))
  .groupBy('str)
  .pivot("char")
  .count
  .show()

+-----+---+---+---+
|  str|  a|  b|  c|
+-----+---+---+---+
|a;b;c|  1|  1|  1|
+-----+---+---+---+
```

Read more about pivot [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html)

The final step is simply to do a left join on the second dataset (first "RESULT").